# Bash append to file, removed during execution. Can this be fixed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I just realised something rather stupid (my side) happened. I am currently running multiple programs on several machines while appending their output.

E.g. machine01 is running "./calc 1 >> calc_one.txt", machine02 is running "./calc 2 >> calc_two.txt" etc.

These calculations run long, and I just found out that something annoying happened. I'm using git, and I was running these programs on a number of the machines. I wrote a new mode of my program and called to run it on machine03.

Because I'm using git, I figured it was save to remove the .txt files in the directory.

I just realised the machines *share* a directory. So I have removed "calc_one.txt" and "calc_two.txt", to which output is being appended.

Now, the programs are such that they actually only print output at the *end*. In the program are a large number of threads (OMP) and these generate results (C++ vector) which are printed after all threads finish.

As such, the stream is still coming. But an experiment with BASH and "sleep" indicates that replacing the .txt file won't make it append to the new file. Is there anything I can do or do I need to start these simulations from scratch?

My sincere thanks for your help,
Daimonie

PS: The system is fedora. I have no administrative privileges.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the process PID. For example:

```
pgrep calc
```

2. Find deleted files. For example:

```
find /proc/12345/fd -ls | grep '(deleted)'
# or (no pid)
lsof | grep calc_one.txt
# ...
lsof -p 12345
```

3. a) Copy the file, (from previous result, here `3`). A snapshot:

```
cp /proc/12345/fd/3 mycopy1.txt
```

3. b) New append file:

```
tail -c +0 -f /proc/12345/fd/3 > mycopy2.txt
```

Where:

`-c +K`, Output bytes starting with the Kth. As we want entire file we say +0
   `-f`   , Follow. Output appended data as the file grows.

Comment: Hey, on my test this does work. But on the actual machine, I can't find the correct file. I get something like `5882926    0 lrwx------   1 daimonie   institute  64 Jan  2 01:53 /proc/59158/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/1\ (deleted)`. I'm guessing it's too old and has been removed?

Comment: @Daimonie: Ach. Sorry. I somehow managed to ignore the redirect `>>` and went for the `calc` program opening internal file descriptor. What does your `/proc/PID/fd/1`  hold?

Comment: Isn't it "pgrep" by the way? Also, it holds the file we're looking for. For some reason, it is blinking.

Comment: Additionally, the program is running in background mode. I just added an ampersand to the `tail...` line before, which worked - I'm assuming this is proper?

Comment: @Daimonie: That sounds good.

Comment: `cp: cannot open /proc/PID/fd/1 for reading: Stale file handle`. This sounds like it could be a problem.

Comment: Sukminder's answer is genius. Could you explain (in your answer) the 3b step a bit? 

Regarding Stale file handle, looks like NFS removed the underlying file. That bodes not well at all for @Daimonie.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Guess I'll have to cancel the simulations and start over (they've been running since 30 dec.). The answer is still very good! :)

Comment: @Daimonie: Do you have a `.nfsXXXXXXXXXX` file in the target directory?

Comment: No, I don't. What would that be? Remark: The question is now academic, as I have restarted the simulations. I also did some things to speed them up by 65%, so I am confident that they will finish by Tuesday.

Comment: @Daimonie: OK. Hope it went OK. The point with the `.nfsNN` was if you redirected your program to a file on a NFS mount. If target file is removed there should be created such a file (which is (likely) removed when program ends).

Comment: Ah. I doubt it was a NFS mount, but I didn't see any `.nfsNN' file. I have taken steps to ensure this doesn't happen again, by always writing to a .backup file in addition to i/o redirection.